# Flutter- How to have differing Text Styles in List

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have a `list` that is populated with the return data of various `var's`

This `list` also has a `text` element preceding the data

I want to have separate weight, size etc for the initial text and then the String being passed in

I have tried RichText  and TextStyle but needed a text function, not a list for it to work correctly

Here is the List which is then passed into a function which pushes it to `ShowDialog`

For example, `Line:` to be `FontWeight.w600` & `$pln` String to be `FontWeight.w400`

```
List data = [
    "Line: $pln", 
    "Departed from: $originname",
    "Destination: $destname",
    "Last seen: $recordedattime",
    ];
```

ShowDialog, where `message` is the `list` from previous function

```
title: Text(title),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(message,
                style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new widget for it, this way you can modify the build however you desire easily.

```dart
class NewTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String prefix;
  final String value;

  NewTextWidget({required String message, Key? key})
      : prefix = message.split(": ")[0],
        value = message.split(": ")[1],
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
          text: prefix,
          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          children: [
            TextSpan(
                text: value,
                style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

The **NewTextWidget** expects the message with the ***prefix: value*** format.

So when you call it you need to update your ListBody as:

```dart
ListBody(
  children: data.map((String message) => NewTextWidget(message: message)).toList()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It all seems okay apart from the new ```ListBody``` which doesn't accept the word ```data``` and returns ```Undefined name 'data'.```. I don't pass the data value into my main.dart method, just the ```message```, perhaps this is why?

Comment: Yes, I just used the same you write in that List data ..., use message in this case

Comment: I had already tried to replace ```data``` with ```message``` and the ```.map``` command then red underlined with the error ```The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'String'.```. Is there a way to fix this, I've looked and found nothing. Thank you

Comment: In this anwser I considered passing your entire list, if this is not the case just remove the map statement and call: `ListBody(children: [NewTextWidget(message: message)])`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to run and the error ```(RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1)``` has shown on line ``` value = message.split(": ")[1],```. Why could this be?

Comment: I think I know why this doesn't work. I have just realised the show dialog function is used to populate a pop up marker without the split ```:```. The ```ShowDialog``` is part of the SDK which allows metadata to show. All data is passed in as ```message```, be it my ```List data``` or a String for the opening screen.  So for one use I need to pass a ```List``` in, and another just a String for example. The RangeError is showing on the first ```ShowDialog```  which is a String. How can I go about different text entrys? Sorry for not realising sooner!

Comment: To use this widget you must pass a String, if in your case you have a list, you should map it element by element and returning a instance of NewTextWidget. If you want to generalize this widget to be capable to match different formats other than: **prefix: value**, you can customize the widget's build method or create a new widget tha fits better for the case.